# Copy files to directory outside project with Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, copy, taskmanager

I'm looking for a more efficient way to deploy my WordPress themes. Right now I create the theme and when finished I copy the contents into a new folder without all my Node, Grunt and other dev files. My dev environment runs on DesktopServer, which has an auto-deploy option, but this also copies unwanted dev files.

Could I use Grunt to create a task that when fired copies specific files and folders from /themes/dev-theme/ to /themes/production-ready-theme/ ? This way I have a clean theme that can easily be zipped or uploaded to the production server.

Update: I just thought of a possible solution to run grunt-contrib-copy from my themes directory. This Grunt module would let me control which files to copy. But perhaps there is a more clean or efficient method to accomplish this task.

Comment: Maybe you will find this interesting: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy

Comment: I currently use this module to copy processed css files to a directory inside my working project. Can it also be used to copy files outside the project folder? Or would I need to run the task from the themes folder?

Comment: You are right probably that you can't access global directories from this module. I just thought about a workaround solution, maybe you could use a shell command: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [Grunt Shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) module you could simply add this to your grunt file:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        moveTemlates: {
            command: 'mv /themes/dev-theme/* /themes/production-ready-theme/'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for and easy to integrate in my current workflow, perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

The grunt-contrib-copy module does have the possibility to copy files up the directory tree after all. I just tried it out using these setting in my grunt.js file and it worked.

Grunt Shell gets the job done. But if you already have grunt-contrib-copy installed in your project you could just use this.

```
      copy: {
          main: {
                src: ['css/*', 'img/*', 'icons/*', 'js/*', 'lang/*', 'lib/*', '*.php', '*.css'],
          dest: '../production-theme/'
          }
      },
```